# XMLHttpRequest Select value

Tags: python, xmlhttprequest, httprequest

I try to select a value from a XLR file.
This is my code

`try:

```
 data2='http://192.168.10.143/status'
 #print(data2)

 response = requests.post(data2)
 print("Status code: ", response.status_code)

 data = (response.json())
 print("Printing Entire Post Request")
 print(response.json())
 print("##########################")


 json_str = json.dumps(data)

 resp = json.loads(json_str)

 print (resp)
 print("***********************")


 value =resp['meters']
 value = value[0]
 print(value)`
```

And this is the Output

`{'power': 0.0, 'overpower': 0.0, 'is_valid': True, 'timestamp': 1678032135, 'counters': [0.0, 0.0, 0.0], 'total': 1468}`

Does anyone know how I can get the value from "power"

I want to have the value in my case 0.0. But I have no idea left how to do.

Thx

I tried to write in arrays but it doesent work.

Comment: Maybe `response.json()['meters'][0]['power']`?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it for my own this is the hole xml file

```
{"wifi_sta":{"connected":true,"ssid":"home","ip":"192.168.10.143","rssi":-51},"cloud":{"enabled":true,"connected":true},"mqtt":{"connected":false},"time":"16:37","unixtime":1678030622,"serial":60960,"has_update":false,"mac":"40F520004FBA","cfg_changed_cnt":0,"actions_stats":{"skipped":0},"lights":[{"ison":false,"source":"http","has_timer":false,"timer_started":0,"timer_duration":0,"timer_remaining":0,"mode":"white","brightness":100,"transition":0}],"meters":[{"power":0.00,"overpower":0.00,"is_valid":true, "timestamp":1678034222,"counters":[2.492, 0.000, 0.000],"total":1473}],"inputs":[{"input":0,"event":"","event_cnt":0},{"input":0,"event":"","event_cnt":0}],"tmp":{"tC":43.60,"tF":110.47, "is_valid":true},"calibrated":true,"calib_progress":0,"calib_status":0,"calib_running":0,"wire_mode":1,"forced_neutral":false,"overtemperature":false,"loaderror":0,"overpower":false,"debug":0,"update":{"status":"idle","has_update":false,"new_version":"20221027-104444/v1.12.1-ga9117d3","old_version":"20221027-104444/v1.12.1-ga9117d3"},"ram_total":49672,"ram_free":34732,"fs_size":233681,"fs_free":116715,"uptime":58497}`
```

And this is soluten its the xml from shelly 1

```
import time
import datetime
import requests
import json
import sys
import os
from subprocess import Popen
import re
import replace


try:

    data2='http://192.168.10.143/status'
    #print(data2)

    response = requests.post(data2)
    print("Status code: ", response.status_code)

    data = (response.json())
    #print("Printing Entire Post Request")
    #print(response.json())

    json_str = json.dumps(data)

    resp = json.loads(json_str)

    #print (resp)
    print("****************************************************")


    onoff = resp['lights']
    onoff = str(onoff[0])
    onoff = onoff.replace("{", "")
    onoff = onoff.replace("}", "")
    onoff = onoff.replace(",", ":")
    onoff = onoff.replace(" ", "")
    onoff = onoff.split(":")
    onoff = str(onoff[1])
 
    if onoff == "False":
        onoff = 0
    if onoff == "True":
        onoff = 1

    print("Status Licht ", onoff)
    print("************************************************************")

    data2='http://192.168.10.143/status'
    #print(data2)
    response = requests.post(data2)
    print("Status code: ", response.status_code)

    data = (response.json())
    #print("Printing Entire Post Request")
    #print(response.json())

    json_str = json.dumps(data)

    resp = json.loads(json_str)

    #print (resp)
    print("***********************")
    power =resp['meters']
    power = str(power[0])
    power = power.replace("{", "")
    power = power.replace("}", "")
    power = power.replace("[", "")
    power = power.replace("]", "")
    power = power.replace(",", ":")
    power = power.replace(" ", "")
    power = power.split(":")
    power = float(power[1])

    print("Aktuelle Leistung ",power, " Watt")
      
except Exception as e:

    print("error ",e)
```